# Optimizing a function involving NDSolve results in error messages

Tags: programming, numerical-integration, differential-equations, mathematical-optimization

I want to minimize a function `f` with `NMinimize` but an error occurs that says:

```
f[l_] := (
  kk = NDSolve[{y'[x] == 2*x + 3, y[l] == 0}, y, {x, 0, l}];
  out = Evaluate[y[0] /. kk];
  out[[1]])

NMinimize[{f[t], 0 <= t <= 10}, f, t]
```

> During evaluation of In[18]:= NDSolve::ndsv: Cannot find starting
>   value for the variable y. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[18]:= ReplaceAll::reps:
>   {NDSolve[{(y^[Prime])[x]==3+2 x,y[{t}]==0},y,{x,0,{t}}]} is neither a
>   list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be
>   used for replacing. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[18]:= NMinimize::argrx: NMinimize called with
>   3 arguments; 2 arguments are expected. >>
>
> ```
> Out[18]= NMinimize[{y[0], 0 <= t <= 10}, f, t]
> ```

How can I fix the function `f` to avoid this problem?

Comment: Try `f[l_?NumericQ] := Module[{kk = First[NDSolve[{\[FormalY]'[x] == 2 x + 3, \[FormalY][l] == 0}, \[FormalY], {x, 0, l}]]}, \[FormalY][0] /. kk]`

Comment: This article helps explain what ?NumericQ is doing. http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3820

Answer (score 8):

Check this

```
f[l_?NumericQ] := Module[
{kk, y, x, out},
kk = NDSolve[{y'[x] == 2*x + 3, y[l] == 0}, y, {x, 0, l}];
out = Evaluate[y[0] /. kk];
out[[1]]
];
res=NMinimize[{f[t], 0 <= t <= 10}, t]
```

it gives

```
{-130., {t -> 10.}}
```

You can check if the answer is correct by plotting your function.

```
Show[Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 10}, Frame -> True], 
Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{res[[2, 1, 2]], res[[1]]}]}]]
```

[image]

Welcome to the site! But please check the other questions in the site as similar questions have been many times answered.

Comment: thank you very much J.M. and dear PlatoManiac